# What are the valid `query` keys for `sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create` that work for accessing a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am interested in using the [`sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create) constructor, but I am finding the documentation to be a too brief on the details to understand how to use it.

Here are the parameters:

- `drivername`: the name of the database backend. This name will correspond to a module in sqlalchemy/databases or a third party plug-in.
- `username`: The user name
- `password`: database password. Is typically a string, but may also be an object that can be stringified with `str()`.
- `host`: The name of the host
- `port`: The port number
- `database`: The database name
- `query`: A dictionary of string keys to string values to be passed to the dialect and/or the [DBAPI](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/glossary.html#term-DBAPI) upon connect. To specify non-string parameters to a Python DBAPI directly, use the `create_engine.connect_args` parameter to `create_engine()`. See also `URL.normalized_query` for a dictionary that is consistently string->list of string.

The parameter I am confused about is `query`. I don't know how to use it for PostgreSQL. I found an example that works for Microsoft SQL:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# CONFIG
SERVER_NAME = 'FOO'
DATABASE_NAME = 'BAR'

# QUERY
QUERY = '''SELECT * FROM table'''

# CONNECTION
CONNECTION_STRING = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server={%s};Database=%s;Trusted_Connection=yes;' % (
    SERVER_NAME,
    DATABASE_NAME
    )

CONNECTION_URL = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc",
 query={"odbc_connect": CONNECTION_STRING})


CONNECTION = create_engine(CONNECTION_URL)
```

Which makes it evident that I can use it for passing in the connection string. I think I can replace `"mssql+pyodbc"` with `"postgresql+psycopg2"`, but I don't know what to replace `"odbc_connect"` with.

1. (short-term) What can I put into `query` to change to PostgreSQL and
2. (more fundamentally) where can I find detailed documentation for understanding the possible inputs of the `query` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query=` is how we specify anything that follows `?` in the string version of the connection URL. (The values following `?` have long been known as the "querystring" in a URL.)

`odbc_connect` is a special case for ODBC connections (e.g., `mssql+pyodbc://`). There is no equivalent for PostgreSQL because none of the supported drivers for the `postgresql` dialect use ODBC. So the answer to

> What can I put into `query` to change to PostgreSQL

is "Nothing. That is not an option."

As for things you *can* put into `query` for PostgreSQL, any of the additional `key=value` listed in the [psycopg2 driver documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2) could be used. For example, if you wanted to create an Engine that uses database connections where [SSL is required](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#ssl-connections) you would use something like

```py
connection_url = URL.create(
    "postgresql+psycopg2",
    username="scott",
    password="tiger",
    host="192.168.0.199",
    database="test",
    query={"sslmode": "require"}
)
print(connection_url)
# postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test?sslmode=require
```